# Why instance variable's value are changed as per function values

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have a class. I have two instance member variables x and y, and the class also has a function which again takes two variables named x and y.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public int Add(int x , int y)
    {
        return (x + y);
    }
}
```

Now I am creating an instance of the class and assigning the values to the instance variables and If I call the function using the same instance the value of the instance variables is getting changed to the values which I am passing as parameter to the function as shown below

```
        MyClass abs = new MyClass();
        abs.x = 10;
        abs.y = 11;
        Console.WriteLine(abs.Add(12, 13).ToString());
```

While debugging I found that the value of instance variables is changed to 12 and 13 respectively. Why is it so? What exactly is happening.

Comment: Check again, i don't see it changing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sure the instance fields are not changed. Most likely you misinterpreted your debugger output. If you simply watch `x` or `y` while you are in the `Add` method the debugger (watch window) will show the values of the method parameters. You need to watch `this.x` or `this.y`.

That's also one of the reasons why I always start my instance fields with a underscore.

Comment: While debugging if I put the cursor on the instance variables it shows the changed values

Comment: @Vikram The mouseover tooltips don't account for any scoping. They just display the value that the variable with the name under the mouse cursor has in the current scope, like the watch window would do.

Comment: Manually add `x`, `y`, `this.x` and `this.y` to a watch window and you will see the mouse tooltip is showing the wrong value.

Answer (score 3):

Well it should not change and the best way to confirm would be add this too

```
Console.WriteLine(abs.Add(12, 13).ToString()); // output 25
Console.WriteLine(abs.x + abs.y); // output 21
```

to check the value of the field you need to use `this.x`

For more details [Variable names should not match field names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182216%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: +1 for link, (IMO the two writelines don't help much but I can see why you added them)

Answer (score 1):

Debugger shows the `x` value for the scope in which the break point is located. Pointing the member declaration with mouse does not necessarily required to show that variable's value. Check `this.x` in watch view.